# How do you create a button that works in javascript?

Tags: javascript, button, dice

**EDIT:** So a few solutions work. Thing is, they work in codepen.io. But when I try to reload the actual HTML page from my computer to Chrome, the button clicks and shows nothing. Chrome is saying: 'dice.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
    at dice.js:12.' How do I fix that?

I've looked at multiple similar questions that have different answers, and none of the answers I've tried has worked. I was able to make a random dice roll with the below code:

```
const min = 1;
const max = 7;

function diceRoll(random) {
    random = 0;
    while (random <= 0) {
        random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
        document.write('Dice # ' + random);
    }
}
```

My html is:

```
<button id="roll">Throw Dice</button>
```

I haven't learned how to make buttons work, or how to start the javascript (other than writing it in the console. Can anyone help with how to create a button to make it work so I don't have to use the console? See below for what I've tried:

```
let button = document.getElementById('roll');

button.onclick = function() {
    let result = diceRoll();
    printNumber(result);
};
```

Another try:

```
 document.getElementById("roll").onclick = diceRoll();
```

And another:

```
document.getElementById("roll").onclick = function() {
    diceRoll();
};
```

Comment: The `onclick` works for me (last version you show). `diceRoll` doesn't return anything, so `let result = diceRoll()` version won't work as you expect. `onclick = diceRoll()` could be `onclick = diceRoll`. Can you post your code as a [runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) that reproduces the problem ([mcve]) and explain the desired result? Thanks.

Comment: https://codepen.io/CatMeza/pen/pogzJrj It works on load, not when clicking the button.

Comment: Remove the `()` as I describe above. You want to set the `onclick` property to the function object itself without invoking it. If you invoke it, you're setting `onclick = undefined` and producing a side effect (the `document.write`).

Comment: Wait, I just tried the last one as well in code pen and it works. But when I open the html page in Chrome, it does nothing...what's going on?

Comment: Your button should have an onclick function calling the JAVASCRIPT function like ```<button onclick="diceRoll() " id="roll">Throw Dice</button>```

Comment: I didn't even think of that, thank you! Now I just have to figure out a way to keep the button visible so I can use it again without reloading, lol

Comment: Just wanted to know. Is your JS in a separate file? if yes, is it included at the bottom or the top of the page?

Comment: Its a seperate file, and its the only thing inside the file (so top)

Comment: Try including the file at the bottom of the body tag...it should work then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script>
            const min = 1;
            const max = 7;

            function diceRoll(random) {
                random = 0;
                while (random <= 0) {
                    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
                    document.write('Dice # ' + random);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form onsubmit='diceRoll()'>
            <button>Throw Dice</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Codepen puts your script *after* the html, so the page is loaded by the time it gets to your script. This is important because if your script says `document.getElementById('roll')` but the page hasn't loaded, that element doesn't exist yet, and you won't have anything to be referencing- so you'll get `null` instead. That's no good. I bet that when you make a local file, you're not doing the same thing Codepen is doing. You're probably doing this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            const min = 1;
            const max = 7;

            function diceRoll() {
                let random = 0;
                while (random <= 0) {
                    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
                    document.write('Dice # ' + random);
                }
            }
            
            let button = document.getElementById('roll');
            
            button.onclick = function() {
                diceRoll();
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="roll">Throw Dice</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

When you should be doing this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            const min = 1;
            const max = 7;

            function diceRoll() {
                let random = 0;
                while (random <= 0) {
                    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
                    document.write('Dice # ' + random);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="roll">Throw Dice</button>
        <script>
            let button = document.getElementById('roll');
            
            button.onclick = function() {
                diceRoll();
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Or this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            const min = 1;
            const max = 7;

            function diceRoll() {
                let random = 0;
                while (random <= 0) {
                    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
                    document.write('Dice # ' + random);
                }
            }
            
            window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
                document.getElementById('roll').onclick = diceRoll;
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="roll">Throw Dice</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Or even this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            const min = 1;
            const max = 7;

            function diceRoll() {
                let random = 0;
                while (random <= 0) {
                    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
                    document.write('Dice # ' + random);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="roll" onclick="diceRoll();">Throw Dice</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Believe it or not, there are still more ways to accomplish this that I haven't listed. The important thing is that they all **let the element you're referencing load in the page before trying to grab it in JavaScript**. Just choose the style of doing this that you like most and go with that.

---

### Side note:

I saw that you also want a way to keep the button on the page. `document.write` clears the page, but you can just write your own output function that'll add your custom message to the [innerHTML](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) of a div on the page like this:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      const min = 1;
      const max = 7;

      function diceRoll() {
        let random = 0;
        while (random <= 0) {
          random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
          output('Dice # ' + random);
        }
      }

      function output(message) {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += message + "<br/><br/>";
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="roll" onclick="diceRoll();">Throw Dice</button>
    <div id="output"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And as an extra bonus tip, using a tool called [randojs](https://github.com/nastyox/Rando.js), you can do this all as simply as this:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="roll" onclick="document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += 'Dice # ' + rando(1, 6) + '<br/><br/>';">Throw Dice</button>
    <div id="output"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```